# Can I use Ctrl-, as a hotkey in a Winforms menu item?

Tags: winforms, menuitem, hotkeys

When I open the ShortcutKeys menu, comma is not there. Oemcomma is there, and it works. But when your menu item says the hotkey is "Ctrl+Oemcomma" that's pretty ugly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing you can't fix with a wee bit of code:

```
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        fooToolStripMenuItem.ShortcutKeyDisplayString = "Ctrl+,";
    }
```